# Can you create semi transparent text

Tags: html, colors

I would like to know if there is a way to add transparency to text in forums.
I know of using [color=transparent] but that makes it fully transparent

Is there a proper coding to add transparency like 50% or so?

Example
[color=#FF0000] red [/color]

Comment: You can use either the `opacity` CSS property or `RGBA` text colors. Google should tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS:

```
.transparent_text {
    color: gray; /* fallback */
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

and

```
<div class="transparent_text">Hello</div>
or
<div style="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">World</div>
```

The last value is the transparency (this is semi-transparent-black). 0 for completely transparent, 1 for opaque

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xUgYP/

Comment: +1, however I strongly suggest doing something like `color:black; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)`, as this will allow older browsers to have a colour to fall back to.

Comment: @Kolink haha I just remembered to add that (thanks though anyways)